# Pointers inside Struct

Tags: c++, c, typedef

I have this code:

```
typedef struct s1{
    void *x;
} s1;

typedef struct s2{
    unsigned char y[5];
} s2;

s1 *s1_g;
s2 *s2_g;
```

What I wanted to do is to point pointer x to variable y.

I tried doing this:

```
s1_g->x = s2_g->y
```

but receives a segmentation error

Anyone can please enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

If that's all of the code, then you haven't even initialized `s1_g` and `s2_g`. So dereferencing them will no doubt cause a segmentation error.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a valid object at the pointer location. Since, there is no valid object at `s1_g`, behaviour is undefined on dereferencing them.